# Nullable TimePicker in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nullable, timepicker

I'm using `TimePicker` for displaying time in my app. When time is already set then it displays correctly, but when time is not set, then it display default 12 : 00 AM time. So I just want display `null` value when time is not set.
Is it possible to set `nullable` value to `TimePicker` in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 2):

You can create one custom `View` with a `TimePicker` and `Label`. If no time is selected then "hh:mm" will appear otherwise the time will appear on the label. To show the timepicker dialog there is a `tapGestureRecognizer` which will set the focus to timepicker when label is tapped.

```
public class NullableTimePicker : ContentView
{
    private const string NullTimeLabel = "hh : mm";
    private readonly TimePicker _timePicker;
    private readonly Label _label;                

    public static readonly BindableProperty TimeProperty = BindableProperty.Create<NullableTimePicker, TimeSpan?>(t => t.Time, null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnTimeChanged);

    public NullableTimePicker()
    {
         _label = new Label
         {
              Text = NullTimeLabel,
              HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
              VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
              HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
              VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
              TextColor = Color.Black,
              FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label))
         };

         _timePicker = new TimePicker
         {
              IsVisible = false,
              HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
              VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
         };

         Content = new StackLayout
         {
              Children =
              {
                   _label,
                   _timePicker
              },
              Padding = 0,
              Spacing = 0,
              Margin = 0
         };

         Padding = 0;
         Margin = 0;

         var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
         tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped;
         GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

         _timePicker.PropertyChanged += timePicker_PropertyChanged;

         PropertyChanged += NullableTimePicker_PropertyChanged;
   }

  private void NullableTimePicker_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
         if (_label != null && e.PropertyName == IsEnabledProperty.PropertyName)
         {
               _label.TextColor = IsEnabled ? Color.Black : Color.Gray;
         }
  }

  private void timePicker_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
         if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName && _timePicker != null)
         {
                    Time = _timePicker.Time;
         }
   }

   private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
          if (IsEnabled == false)
          {
               return;
          }

          if (_timePicker.IsFocused)
          {
              _timePicker.Unfocus();
          }

          _timePicker.Focus();
     }

     private static void OnTimeChanged(BindableObject bindable, TimeSpan? oldvalue, TimeSpan? newvalue)
     {
           var nullableTimePicker = bindable as NullableTimePicker;
           if (nullableTimePicker != null && oldvalue != newvalue)
           {
               nullableTimePicker.Time = newvalue;
           }
     }

     public TimeSpan? Time
     {
          get
          {
               return GetValue(TimeProperty) as TimeSpan?;
          }
          set
          {
               SetValue(TimeProperty, value);

               if (value.HasValue && _timePicker.Time != value)
               {
                   _timePicker.Time = value.Value;
               }
               SetLabelText(value);
           }
      }

      private void SetLabelText(TimeSpan? value)
      {
           _label.Text = value.HasValue ? ConvertTimeSpanToString(value.Value) : NullTimeLabel;
      }          
}
```

Comment: This solution has multiple flaws. First, it needs some update for `BindableProperty.Create()` and `OnTimeChanged()`. Second, it should use `Entry` instead of `Label`. But the biggest issue is the following: You can't cancel out a value (set to `null`) if already set (you need a extra button or something like this). And you can't set the time to `00:00` in the beginning, because the property isn't changed. But nice try.

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
/// <summary>
/// DatePicker der null Werte erlaubt
/// </summary>
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// PropertyName für die <c>NullableDate</c> Property
    /// </summary>
    public const string NullableDatePropertyName = "NullableDate";
    /// <summary>
    /// Die BinableProperty
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomDatePicker, DateTime?>(i => i.NullableDate, null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, NullableDateChanged);
    /// <summary>
    /// Datumswert welches null Werte akzeptiert
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? NullableDate
    {
        get
        {
            return (DateTime?)this.GetValue(NullableDateProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Name der <c>NullText</c> Property
    /// </summary>
    public const string NullTextPropertyName = "NullText";
    /// <summary>
    /// Die BindableProperty
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty NullTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomDatePicker, string>(i => i.NullText, default(string), BindingMode.TwoWay);
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Text der angezeigt wird wenn <c>NullableDate</c> keinen Wert hat
    /// </summary>
    public string NullText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(NullTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(NullTextProperty, value);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Name der <c>DisplayBorder</c> Property
    /// </summary>
    public const string DisplayBorderPropertyName = "DisplayBorder";
    /// <summary>
    /// Die BindableProperty
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty DisplayBorderProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomDatePicker, bool>(i => i.DisplayBorder, default(bool), BindingMode.TwoWay);
    /// <summary>
    /// Gibt an ob eine Umrandung angezeigt werden soll oder nicht
    /// </summary>
    public bool DisplayBorder
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(DisplayBorderProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(DisplayBorderProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Erstellt eine neue Instanz von <c>CustomDatePicker</c>
    /// </summary>
    public CustomDatePicker()
    {
        this.DateSelected += CustomDatePicker_DateSelected;

        this.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Wird gefeuert wenn ein neues Datum selektiert wurde
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Der Sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event Argumente</param>
    void CustomDatePicker_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NullableDate = new DateTime(
            e.NewDate.Year, 
            e.NewDate.Month, 
            e.NewDate.Day, 
            this.NullableDate.HasValue ? this.NullableDate.Value.Hour : 0,
            this.NullableDate.HasValue ? this.NullableDate.Value.Minute : 0,
            this.NullableDate.HasValue ? this.NullableDate.Value.Second : 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gefeuert wenn sich <c>NullableDate</c> ändert
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">Der Sender</param>
    /// <param name="oldValue">Der alte Wert</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">Der neue Wert</param>
    private static void NullableDateChanged(BindableObject obj, DateTime? oldValue, DateTime? newValue)
    {
        var customDatePicker = obj as CustomDatePicker;

        if (customDatePicker != null)
        {
            if (newValue.HasValue)
            {
                customDatePicker.Date = newValue.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The variables and methods in this code are well named, but the documentation tags make it less readable. Particularly as they're in German.

Comment: @Alessandro thank you for response, but I looking for Nullable Time picker, TimePicker uses TimeSpan class for time interval.

Comment: You should mention the [source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/146468/#Comment_146468). It is not your code, it is only copy & paste.